# I can't launch the Flutter app. How to fix?

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, podfile

Errors:

```
Command SwiftVerifyEmittedModuleInterface failed with a nonzero exit code
Using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported
Command SwiftDriver emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure
Flutter Doctor output
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
```

```
\[✓\] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.6, on macOS 13.5.1 22G90 darwin-x64, locale ru-RU)
\[✗\] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
(or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for detailed instructions).
If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
flutter config --android-sdk to update to that location.


\[✓\] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.1)
\[✓\] Chrome - develop for the web
\[!\] Android Studio (not installed)
\[✓\] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2023.2.1)
\[✓\] VS Code (version 1.82.2)`your text`
\[✓\] Connected device (3 available)
\[✓\] Network resources
```

Steps to reproduce:

If you run the application from Xcode or through the flutter run command. I tried to rebuild the project by deleting all pods and cleaning it with flutter clean. Still the same effect.

My Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project

# platform :ios, '13.0'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://git.yoomoney.ru/scm/sdk/cocoa-pod-specs.git'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.

ENV\['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'\] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
'Debug' =\> :debug,
'Profile' =\> :release,
'Release' =\> :release,
}

def flutter_root
generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
end

File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT=(.\*)/)
return matches\[1\].strip if matches
end
raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
use_frameworks!
use_modular_headers!
pod 'SwiftKeychainWrapper'

# pod 'YooKassaPayments', :git =\> 'https://git.yoomoney.ru/scm/sdk/yookassa-payments-swift.git', :tag =\> '6.14.0'

flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
target.build_configurations.each do |config|

# config.build_settings\['BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION'\] = 'NO'

      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
    
                  # You can remove unused permissions heres
                  # for more information: https://github.com/BaseflowIT/flutter-permission-handler/blob/master/permission_handler/ios/Classes/PermissionHandlerEnums.h
                  # e.g. when you don't need camera permission, just add 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=0'
                  config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
                    '$(inherited)',
                    ## dart: PermissionGroup.notification
                    'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=1',
                  ]
            end

end
end
```